# Make required model field optional in OpenCart 2.x.x.x admin (OCmod)

Tags: php, xml, opencart, opencart2.x

I tried to make the required model field in OpenCart optional by writing the following OCmod in OpenCart version 2.0.1.1.

```
<modification>
    <name>Remove required model (OC 2.0+)</name>
    <version>v1.0</version>
    <link>http://www.example.com</link> 
    <author>John Doe</author>
    <code>fv16343000</code>

    <!-- Remove required "Model" from Product controller -->
    <file path="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) > 64)) {]]></search>
        <add position="replace"><![CDATA[if (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) > 64) {]]></add>
    </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

As you can see, I aimed to replace the condition, to make it ignore the minimum length.

I also modified the product_form.tpl (removed the "required" class that it had next to form-group):

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-model"><?php echo $entry_model; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="model" value="<?php echo $model; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_model; ?>" id="input-model" class="form-control" />
          <?php if ($error_model) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_model; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Then I tried adding the product without the model, the asterisk was gone but the error still popped (saying that I need to complete the field with a minimum of 1 char to max 64 chars).

I thought my OCmod might not be good enough so I tried editing the controller product.php directly as shown in the OCmod. Error still there so I completely deleted the condition and the following code from the .tpl:

```
  <?php if ($error_model) { ?>
  <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_model; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Removing the bootstrap class worked (not showing the asterisk so it works) but for some reason the field is still required, even with the condition in the controller gone.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the model field optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by using a OCmod. The correct way to remove the model is this:

```
<!-- Remove required class from register.tpl-->
<file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
<operation>
    <search offset="1" index="2"><![CDATA[<div class="form-group required">]]></search>
    <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<div class="form-group">]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
<!-- Comment the error line from the controller-->
<file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
<operation>
    <search><![CDATA[$this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model');]]></search>
    <add position="replace"><![CDATA[//$this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model');]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
```

This code also works as a VQmod (if you use the proper tags before this).

For those that don't understand how OCmods work and still want to hardcode the removal of the mandatory model here's what you need to do:

- open admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl
- search for the `<div class="form-group required">` that is relevant for the model field and remove the `required` class
- open the admin/controller/catalog/product.php file
- look for this line: `$this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model');`
- comment it

You're done.

Answer (score 1):

Once you apply a vQmod the file you are overriding is rewritten to the *vqcache* folder along with the modifications. So altering the original file no longer takes effect.

Clear vQmod cache by deleting the corresponding file in the *vqcache* folder. You could also inspect the file in that same folder to make sure your most recent mod has taken effect.

Now moving on to what you are trying to do, removing the length limit. To accomplish that, simply replace the if statement with `if (false){` to ensure it never triggers.

Comment: I tried completely deleting the condition (without the OCmod active) and it seems like it's not triggered from there. I still get the error. I'm confused, why would it be there if it's not used?

Answer (score -1):

I have developed a free extension that makes the model field optional when adding a product. I hope this is what you were looking for - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=25426.

Joel